# REACT NATIVE - View Image from dynamically(!) created Object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm constructing an object from various input sources, including dynamically created references to images:

```
// ...
myObject.imgRef = require(`./files/${varname1}-${varname2}.png`);
// ...
```

I'm then trying to display these images via

```
//...
<Image source={myObject.imgRef} (...) />
//...
```

but get the error message that *require* constitutes an invalid call...

Please ...help?

*[I've already tried to tackle this from different sides, the here-mentioned approach seemed to be the most sensible one to me. I kinda also see the problem here, but am desperately trying to work around the fact that image names in* require *have to be known statically (according to the DOCs).]*

Comment: You can’t dynamically require a file in react native